# Spring Social Spring Security with java config issue on tomcat7

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am new to Java config in Spring, I am having problem with this Spring Security Spring Social project. Project is hosted on Github.
https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples/tree/master/sign-in/spring-mvc-normal

When the webapp is executed on Apache tomcat 7 it throws the below issue. It works fine on Jetty server. Java gurs can you help me with this issue on tomcat.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: SpringSocialConfigurer depends on org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository. No single bean of that type found in application context.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: SpringSocialConfigurer depends on org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository. No single bean of that type found in application context.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SpringSocialConfigurer depends on org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository. No single bean of that type found in application context.
    at org.springframework.social.security.SpringSocialConfigurer.getDependency(SpringSocialConfigurer.java:90)
    at org.springframework.social.security.SpringSocialConfigurer.configure(SpringSocialConfigurer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.social.security.SpringSocialConfigurer.configure(SpringSocialConfigurer.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:385)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:280)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e48a8614.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e48a8614$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b25538b1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e48a8614.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1125)
    at org.springframework.social.security.SpringSocialConfigurer.getDependency(SpringSocialConfigurer.java:87)
    ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is due to the fact that the [SocialContext](https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples/blob/master/sign-in/spring-mvc-normal/src/main/java/net/petrikainulainen/spring/social/signinmvc/config/SocialContext.java) is annotated with `@Profile("application")`. If you run the application using the maven jetty plugin [is setup to specify the system property](https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples/blob/master/sign-in/spring-mvc-normal/pom.xml#L257) `spring.profiles.active=application` which activates the profile and thus ensures that the UsersConnectionRepository is exposed as a bean.

Ensure you are using the same system property on Tomcat and it should work just fine. If you have trouble specifying the system property, you can remove the `@Profile("application")` from the SocialContext class.

Comment: You got it correct. I removed the @Profile("application") and it worked fine in Apache Tomcat 7. Once again thanks for your input. This has bugged me for two days.